# Not getting INotifyPropertyChanged example to work, I want to update text block from behind

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, inotifypropertychanged

Ive been looking at several `INotifyPropertyChanged` examples but didn't manage to make any of them to work in my project. When I change the value of the property the text in my text block doesn't get updated an I don't know why.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            TextTest = "essa";
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name="")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
        private string textTest = string.Empty;

        public string TextTest {
            get { return this.TextTest; }
            set { this.textTest = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


<Window x:Class="TestProjectComboboxAndPropertyChanged.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Height="200">

        <Button Content="Click me" Click="Button_Click" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></Button>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TextTest,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="55" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>​
```

Comment: I'd say the two answers you have so far are wrong: `The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.`

Comment: @Marcus you are missing the binding of the data context. I have added that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the property name as others have said. According to the docs for `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

> The PropertyChanged event can indicate all properties on the object have changed by using either null or String.Empty as the property name in the PropertyChangedEventArgs.

So even if you were passing `null`/`string.Empty`, it'd work perfectly fine.

The issue you are having is with the binding itself - there is no data context for the binding to work with. To set the data context to the window itself:

```
<Window ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Then your code will work, except for a small error in your property:

```
public string TextTest
{
    get { return this.TextTest; } << WILL CAUSE A STACK OVERFLOW
    set
    {
        this.textTest = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Also, the binding for the `TextBlock` simply needs to be:

```
Text="{Binding TextTest}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the binding. In your Form constructor, bind the Form data context to the current instance.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

    }
```